# How far apart are the quarters of Tyar-Besil?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures

I'm running my group through *Princes of the Apocalypse*. The organization of information in this book is challenging, to say the least.

The group has just gotten to

> one of the first underground temples, which holds one quarter of the ancient dwarven city of Tyar-Besil. (The other three cults hold the other three quarters.) Of course, one of the first things they found is one of the passages that leads to the one of the other quarters, and thus one of the other temples.

What I can't figure out, though, is how much distance it is between the edge of the map on one page and the edge on the other page. Does it bump up against? Is it a mile or more? Hundreds of feet?

Or is this just something I'll need to decide as DM? The first option doesn't make sense to me, because the cults would probably want more space between them. Miles doesn't make any sense to me because that doesn't seem like four quarters of a city, but rather four separate cities.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2):

**A few miles seems a good guess to me**

On the map on page 32 of the book, the temple outposts are about 1-1.5 hexes apart from each other, with one hex being 10 miles. There are stairs/paths down from some of the outposts to the their respective temples, but not to the others, so it seems likely to assume they are somewhere below them.

If you connect all the outposts in the map, you get to a 'mid-point' about 5-10 miles from each outpost. It seems likely that temples are closer to each other than to the outposts, since they are connected to each other, while the outposts are only connected to 'their' temple.

But given the different terrain each of them is located in, putting them too close doesn't make sense either.

Therefore, I think about ~3-5 miles fits best, given the information we have in the book.

**However, the world is yours.**

If you feel that the temples should be closer to each other, or farther away, nothing stops you from doing this in your world.

In my campaign, I've set the whole thing on Athas (Dark Sun), and put the temples about a day's march from each other. I felt that having them closer together would make constant skirmishes the norm, but from the descriptions in the book, it seems to be more of a cold war situation between the temples. They prey on the surface denizens, not on each other.

Comment: I was cautious about trying to rely too much on the surface map, as there's a [bit of hubbub that the scales don't line up](http://www.enworld.org/forum/showthread.php?440360-PotA-Map-Discrepancies/page2). But thanks.

Comment: It's something that plagues many adventures. But don't worry too much, it's easy to fix - just make it the way you prefer it to be ;)

Comment: If you have any printing other than the first, the map scales are fine.  This was an issue with the first printing.